# any alternative to downloading ubuntu-16.04.3-desktop-amd64.iso http://releases.ubuntu.mirror.rafal.ca/16.04.3/ubuntu-16.04.3-desktop-amd64.iso

Tags: downloads, ubuntu-website

any alternative site to download
ubuntu-16.04.3-desktop-amd64.iso
http://releases.ubuntu.mirror.rafal.ca/16.04.3/ubuntu-16.04.3-desktop-amd64.iso

its downloading at 400kbytes/sec for a 1.5G file?

are there any quicker alternatives?

just asking

Comment: Why did you choose `rafal.ca`? Go to ubuntu.com and download. You can also use torrent to download, it is always fast.

Comment: im in Montreali went on ubuntu.com and it directed me there. I wanted the desktop version.

Comment: OK.will dothnks

Comment: You can click alternative downloads and use torrent. you will get full speed of your ISP.

Comment: OK.  Im good now. downloading at 2 to 3 mb/sec.  whew. thnks